# Executable located in location A how to run it in location B?

Tags: command-line, path, executable, chmod

So, I've an executable in my debian server and this executable located in `/home/human/ExecuteIt`, still i cant figure it out how to run my executable in another location.  In my case it is `/home/human/ExecuteIt/FolderWithConfiaguration/Configuration1/`.

Normally for just 1 configuration folder i can just copy/paste an executable to the `/home/human/ExecuteIt/FolderWithConfiaguration/Configuration1/` and then using `sudo chmod +x ./executable` run it successfully, but my executable has several configuration's folders that contains different configuration.

It would be great if i could have my executable separate and execute it with different configuration without copy/pasting. Is there a way to execute my executable in different location?

Comment: here is nothing about env variables

Comment: Okay.  I'll delete that comment, I see you are asking a somewhat different question.  However, I think you should try and clarify it: does the issue have to do with the fact the executable is sourcing configuration on a relative path?

Comment: thanks, yes the executable is sourcing configuration on a relative path, but it is doesn't matters where configuration is in, if i could use something to run the executable in the path where configurations is in

Answer (score 1):

If your executable is sourcing it's configuration from a relative path, that path is relative to the `pwd` (present working directory).  So:

```
> cd /there/locA
> pwd
/there/locA
> /there/stuff/executable
```

The executable will look relative to locB.  Now:

```
> cd /there/locB
> pwd
/there/locB
> /there/stuff/executable
```

The executable will look relative to locB.

If you mean you mean you want to run the executable while the pwd is locB, but magically source the configuration from locB, the answer is that the only way to do that would be somehow tell the executable that, eg, by adding a command-line parameter with which to invoke it, or using a custom environment variable.  Simply copying the executable to locA and then trying to invoke that one specifically from locB expecting it to use locA as the pwd won't work -- the pwd is still locB.

I notice setting $PWD for a single command:

```
> PWD=/there/locA bash -c 'echo $PWD'
/there/locB
```

doesn't work.  So perhaps you cannot spoof the pwd.

Comment: ok, let me try it out :)

Comment: could you explain how an above command lines could perform execution an exe from dirA inside dirB (configuration folder)?

Comment: What I'm saying is, where exe is stored in the filesystem (whether dirA, dirB, or somewhere else) doesn't matter. If you execute it in dirA and it sources configuration using a relative path, then it is being executed in dirA. Moving the exe somewhere else will not matter. In other words: you CANNOT get the shell to pretend you are in some other directory.  Your `pwd` is your `pwd`.  Period. If you want the option to specify a different configuration, then you need to create that option.  If you did not write the exe, then check if it has such an option (good software usually does).

Comment: how could it be like this? As i know it is possible to run an exe with another user, so you wanna say that it is impossible to do so with another folder?

Comment: *"If your executable is sourcing it's configuration from a relative path, that path is relative to the pwd (present working directory)."* I don't think you can assume that in a general case. It'll likely be correct in many cases, but not necessarily all.

Comment: Expanding on what MichaelKjörling said; it is easily possible for the app to reference configurations from where it is located, not `$PWD`. A shell script wanting to get a file in the same directory can do `SOMEVAR="$(dirname $0)/somefile".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, so I'll restate what I understand in my own words. You have a program that looks for its configuration files in the same directory that the program is located in. For example, if you run `/home/human/ExecuteIt/FolderWithConfiaguration/Configuration1/executable`, it looks for configuration files in `/home/human/ExecuteIt/FolderWithConfiaguration/Configuration1`. You want to be able to run the program with different configurations, for example `/home/human/ExecuteIt/FolderWithConfiaguration/Configuration2`. And you don't want to make multiple copies of the program.

You can make [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to the executable in multiple directories, and make symbolic links to all the common files as well. For example, suppose the program requires three files: the executable `executable`, a data file `data`, and a configuration file `config`. You have two different configurations, which you put in
`/home/human/ExecuteIt/FolderWithConfiaguration/Configuration1/config` and `/home/human/ExecuteIt/FolderWithConfiaguration/Configuration2/config`. You have one copy of the executable and the data file, both in `/home/human/ExecuteIt/FolderWithConfiaguration/Configuration1/`. And you make a symbolic link to `/home/human/ExecuteIt/FolderWithConfiaguration/Configuration1/executable` in the directory `/home/human/ExecuteIt/FolderWithConfiaguration/Configuration2/`, as well as a symbolic link to `/home/human/ExecuteIt/FolderWithConfiaguration/Configuration1/data`.

```
cd /home/human/ExecuteIt/FolderWithConfiaguration/Configuration2
ln -s ../Configuration1/executable ../Configuration1/data
```

The symbolic links tell the system to look for the real file in a different place. They don't contain any data themselves, so if you update the executable or the data in `Configuration1`, this applies to all configuration; and there is only one copy of the files, so the additional configurations only require the disk space for the configuration file.

Most programs that behave this way will take the location of the executable into account when looking for data and configuration files. If yours follows the symbolic link, this method won't work. Instead, you can make a [hard link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link). Hard links are multiple paths for the same files; all the hard links to a file are equivalent.

```
cd /home/human/ExecuteIt/FolderWithConfiaguration/Configuration2
ln ../Configuration1/executable ../Configuration1/data
```

This makes it more difficult to update the files as you need to update the file designated by all the paths. Also, all the hard links to the same file have to be on the same filesystem.

Comment: I'm not sure that second-to-last sentence makes much sense. All hard links point to the same *data* (file content), only under different names. Update one, and all the others reflect the change immediately. That's the beauty of hard links: you can place the same content *equivalently* under multiple file names, without having more than one copy of the file, as long as they are all on the same file system.